# css - how to add another div above one with 2 colums layout?

Tags: css, html

Here is my Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LLFpp/

I'm just starting to learn CSS and Divs (moving over from the old tables) and I'm trying to figure out how to place another one of the green div above the already existing green div, with a 20px space between the 2 divs, while keeping the right side div in it's place.

I tried to do it as I would with tables, but then it screws up the entire layout, pushing down the div on the right.

So basically now I have:

```
| |
```

And I need:

```
| |
|
```

Makes sense? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a container for both "green" divs and left allign that one.

something like this:

```
<div id="bigcontainer">
    <green div 1>
    <green div 2>
</div>
<div id="menu">
 <!--whatever-->
</div>
```

**In your CSS**

```
#bigcontainer{float:left;}
```

You can then do whatever you want with the "green divs" without affecting the main design.

hope it's clear enough :)

Comment: Just tried it and for some reason it pushes the right side box way down the page :(

Comment: The width may be the problem, set a fixed width to the "bigcontainer" and allign it to the left so that the menu can stay on the right

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
div.left_box{
    float: left;
 }

div.right_box{
    float: right;
}
```

And then put your two green div sections inside the left_box div.

Answer (score 0):

This will use the left columns parent to prepend new content. By giving an id to title and then adjusting the id in the `el` variable it would be possible to still retain the green background and be under the title. It really depends on what the changing content will be like.

```
$(function(){
 var el = document.getElementById("main");
 var parent = el.parentNode;
 var newContents = document.createElement("div");
 newContents.innerHTML = "<p>New Content</p>";
 newContents.style = "margin-bottom: 20px";
 parent.insertBefore(newContents,el);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLFpp/10/